# Dataset target values selection

Tags: neural-network

Let's say I want to train a neural network to predict whether some state is 'good' or 'bad'. We can think of it as a value function for a board game. So a natural choice would be to place one neuron in an output layer with hyperbolic tangent function activation. Then I need to construct a dataset where for each 'good' position the target value equals  1 and -1 otherwise and train with mean squared error loss function.

So I chose target values in dataset that match my activation function's image. From what I've read this is a common approach. But what if I assign some states greater or lower values than 1 and -1 respectively? Does it make any sense? If so, can we say anything theoretically how such change would affect training?

Comment: Good/bad is a classification task. Why do you train on MSE loss instead of binary binary cross entropy? In case you have a continuous reward from you game, why should it be a problem to do regression (with MSE loss in this case)? How well training works is a matter of try and error. But I don‘t see why there should be any sever problem.

Comment: ok, so say I have a continuous reward and I want my output to be in [-1; 1], is it necessary to scale rewards from dataset to this interval as well?